# Ti.Media.showCamera not showing even if camera permissions are granted Android 6.0 Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

My development environment is mac osx, appcelerator sdk 5.3.0 and testing on google nexus Android 6.0. Ti.Media.showCamera not opening camera even if permissions are granted. Here is my code

```
function openCamera(parms) {
    if (Ti.Media.hasCameraPermissions) {
        Ti.API.error("Yes has camera permission");
        Ti.Media.showCamera({
            success : function(event) {
                parms.source.image = newBlob;
            },
            cancel : function() {
                Ti.API.error("User cancelled pictur selection");
            },
            error : function(error) {
                var a = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                    title : 'Camera Error'
                });
                if (error.code == Ti.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
                    a.setMessage("No Camera Found!");
                } else {
                    a.setMessage('Unexpected Error: ' + error.code);
                }
                a.show();
            },
            mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
            animated : true,
            autoHide : true,
            allowEditing : true,
            saveToPhotoGallery : false,
            showControls : true
        });
    } else {
        Ti.API.error("No camera permission. Asking for Permission");
        Ti.Media.requestCameraPermissions(function(e) {
            Ti.API.error(JSON.stringify(e));
            if (e.success === true) {
                openCamera(parms);
            } else {
                alert("Access denied, error: " + e.error);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

In console log this displayed

> Yes has camera permission
>
> [WARN] :   InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but
>   the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Would someone point me out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiii I think you are missing brackets after hasCameraPermissions. hasCameraPermissions() is a method defined inside Ti.Media.
Use it like this:
`if(hasCameraPermissions()){
//Do you code.....
}`